# How do you install Adobe AIR on an ipad

Tags: ipad

Adobe AIR does not appear in the App Store - this is Australia, on an iPad 2.

Are there geographic restrictions - surely it isn't sideloaded?

Comment: Why would there be Air for iPad anyway? Where did you hear this...

Comment: What is the function that you need to perform on the iPad 2 that would require a program like Adobe Air?

Comment: The sliderocket offline player is an AIR app.

Comment: @Odinulf From Adobe: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/

Comment: Not sure why this came FROM Stack Overflow. This has been revealed to be a programming/framework question, so this question should probably head back TO Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jason Since the asker wants to install the Air framework in order to get a third-party app to run, it seems that this question isn't really about development.

Comment: I agree - and I am the op.  The post to stackoverflow initially was simply an error as I didn't pay attention to which stack I was logged into.

Comment: Paul - could you clarify what you are looking for in your question? Are you looking for a program that runs on iOS and lets air programs run? Are you looking for advice whether any store app will run air apps or something else? Perhaps with some clarity, we can get you an actual answer that works for you...

Comment: @bmike: I appreciate the flag on this, but I don't think the intent of the OP really matters here; the question is simple enough. This question is almost a month old now and since resolved (more or less) simply by its age.

Answer (score 14):

You don't.

There aren't geographic restrictions: there are universal restrictions. As is the case with Flash—or pretty much anything that can interpret arbitrary code—Apple is not going to allow Air onto iOS.

Comment: Yup, I am pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Adobe don't appear to be aware of this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/whats-new-in-air-26.html and system requirements: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/

Comment: If I understand this correctly, Adobe's AIR development tools let you generate iPhone apps. These would be self-contained—you wouldn't install AIR on an iOS device and run an AIR app on top of that. And it's dependent on the developer choosing to target iOS in the first place.

Comment: It looks like the AIR runtime is actually embedded into each ios app according to the developer release notes.

Answer (score 4):

Given your comment on [Adam Rice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22802/how-do-you-install-adobe-air-on-an-ipad/22805#22805)'s answer. I believe that you're mistaken about how one would use Air with an iOS device.

You don't actually put Air on the device. You write your app with Air, then use Adobe's packager to [turn it into a native iOS app](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html).

Comment: Sure.  It is only native in the sense that the AIR runtime and AIR app are not separate.  If you read the developer notes you will find the AIR runtime is packaged in with the AIR app. This was a sensible compromise.

Comment: @Paul - No, Apple doesn't allow alternative runtimes. What you write in Air gets compiled down to Objective C.